# Counting list elements produce wrong answer

Tags: python

I am trying to count how many characters are in this list, using 2 loops.
And there are clearly 31 characters but the output says I have 32...
What is going on here??

```
purebin = ['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '1000000']
count = 0 
for x in purebin:
    i = 0
    for j in purebin[i]:
         count = count + 1
print(purebin)
print(count)
```

output is following

```
['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '1000000']
32
```

Comment: You're checking the first element four times. Hint: you went through `purebin[i]` instead of `x`.

Comment: I realized it 10 sec after I uploaded this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
for j in purebin[i]:
```

You repeatedly look at the first item (only) of `purebin` which has eight characters.

Add a print statement to see what is happening

```
for j in purebin[i]:
    print(purebin[i])
    count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is reseting **i** to **0** at every iteration of the loop.

Also You can use the `len` function:

```
count = 0 
for element in purebin:
    count += len(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `for j in x` as that is the iterable you're concerned with in the 2nd loop

```
purebin = ['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '1000000']
count = 0 
for x in purebin:
    for j in x:
         count = count + 1
```

In your version all you're doing is counting the first string over and over because `purebin[count]` = `purebin[0]` which is `'11111111'`